# TYPO3 phpexcel_service Could not close zip file error

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

When I am trying to install the **TYPO3** extension `phpexcel_service` on **localhost** 
I get following error: `Could not close zip file...`

I found many soluitons to similar questions but none of them helps. 
I have enough space and I do not have any problem with permissions.

I was able to install the extension on a server but it is not a solution that would allow a normal development.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue, I tried to install from Extension Manager > Get Extension

Search "phpexcel_service" and install it.

It's work fo me. try it may your help :)